# Store multiple files (attachments) in Azure Table Storage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage, asp.net-core-1.1

I have some `Mail`'s that I add to an **Azure Table** Storage. The Mail should have some attachments...

I am reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads), and try to understand the logic, in the Azure table I should probably store Attachments as `byte[]`

```
public class Mail {
    string Subject {get; set;}
    byte[] Attachments {get; set;} 
}
```

Say I have a corresponding ViewModel:

```
public class MailEditViewModel {
    string Subject {get; set;}
    List<IFromFile> Attachments {get; set;} 
}
```

- How should now I transform the `byte[]` to a `List<IFromFile>` and vice-versa?

I have the article code for a single file:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(MailViewModel model)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if  (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new Mail {
          Subject = model.Subject
        };
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // ?? await model.Attachments.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            // ?? user.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

- Is there a way to keep in a AzureTable `byte[]` multiple files?

Answer (score 4):

Do not save attachments to Azure **Table** Storage.

Max size of a table entity [is 1MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#scalability-targets-for-blobs-queues-tables-and-files), including attribute names (not only values).

Use Azure **Blob** Storage for storing files.

Comment: Will I be able to link the Mail record in the Table Storage with the Blob? There are also Azure File Storage... a little bit complicated to understand what is better Blob or File storages for the attachements (word, excel, pdf files, etc)...

Comment: also I find out that the `byte[]` AzureTable field should be up to 64 KB in size.

Comment: You may save file body to Blob (with random/unique names) and put blob file name/path into Table attribute(s).

Comment: File storage useful when your (very old) app supports only "local drives" - you can "attach" cloud storage as local drive without changes in app.

Comment: So, the Attachments fileld should rather be of List<string> or even maybe csv string... with blob paths(csv paths) inside